# npm lodash module OR Sequelize.utils._?

Tags: sequelize.js, lodash

Both lodash library having all required function. So
why we require separate lodash module( in backend) instead of using sequelize provided Sequelize.utils._ module?

Answer (score 1):

You should use your own module. Sequelize might update their lodash version or change how they're using it and it could break your project in all sorts of places. It could potentially cause huge problems later down the line.

Also if you're using the same version(or version range) of lodash that they are, npm(version 3 and above) will only download the module once for both to save space.

So unless you're very limited for disk space or memory, always install into your own project. Don't use your dependencies dependencies.